# Cannot set label.Text values in a modal popup from GridView values (in BoundFields)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a GridView with several BoundFields from a compact SQL database (I am using the older Visual Studio Express 2010, in C#)

I am experimenting, and have read that if your GridView fields are BoundFields rather than Template, extraction of the value should be as easy as:

```
Label.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

(considering you are aiming for the value of the selected row)

I am trying to show that value in a Modal Popup Extender, and it's showing blank. No error message at all, and the debugger just shows the value blank all the time. Since I am quite a beginner, I am guessing that probably my error is in the placement of the parts, but I couldn't figure it out:

My GridView definition has this:

```
onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Then later on I have a Panel with a Modal Popup Extender:

```
<asp:Panel ID="view" runat="server" CssClass="pnlBackGround">
    <asp:Label ID="vid" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="vclose" runat="server" Text="Cerrar" />
</asp:Panel>


<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" 
     PopupControlID="view" 
     OkControlID="vclose" 
     TargetControlID="f1" 
     BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
     runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And the function that is giving me problems is the one called on selected index changed:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 vid.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
 this.ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
 }
```

I think that this code should grab the value of the first cell of the selected row, and place it as text of the "vid" label, and then open the popup extender with that information.

What (probably silly) thing am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with the ajaxToolkit.  But I do recall the ModalPopupExtender to be HARD to work with.  That being said, everything here looks right to me. About the only thing I can think of is that "GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text" might actually be blank?  Have you ruled that out?

Comment: And just to be sure, you do see the popup?  And the close button works right?

Comment: Yes, the popup shows properly and the close button works fine. The GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text contains an id value of 1 digit, that is the primary key of the database table. I want to grab that information to show it on the popup, and later on to run other sql queries.

Comment: Ok.  If you put a break point and then add this to the watch: "GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text", does it show "1"?

Comment: It shows "", so I know that the value is not arriving to the label because is not being properly acquired from the gridview. But the value I want is located in the very first cell of the row, so it's cells[0]. That's pretty strange. I will do it in javascript if I cannot solve it, but it's interesting why I am getting that problem.

Comment: I don't think the module popup is the problem.  The issue seems to be getting the value from the gridview, and it won't be any different with Javascript.  Try putting the entire gridview into the watch, and expanding it down so you can see each cell and their values.