# Where do I have to attach this dynamic buttons to make them appear inside the table cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This has been puzzling me for a while. I have a `label` in asp (C#) where I created a table to store the values received from an sql database. It looks like this (this is the loop that gathers the sql values and puts them in a table structure):

```
 while (reader.Read())
      {
      Label1.Text += "<tr><td>"
      + reader[0] + "</td><td>" 
      + reader[1] + "</td><td>" 
      + reader[2] + "</td><td>" 
      + reader[3] + "</td><td>" 
      + reader[4] + "</td><td>" 
      + reader[5] + "</td><td>";
      Button btn = new Button();
      btn.ID = "del" + reader[0];
      btn.Text = "Borrar";
      this.Label1.Controls.Add(btn);
      Label1.Text += "</td></tr>";
      }
```

I omit the common parts of the table (they are outside the loop).

The puzzling question is: The table appears as content of `Label1`, but attaching the buttons to that label doesn't work. If I attach them to

```
 this.form1.Controls.Add(btn)
```

then it attaches them to the main form, outside the table.

I am thinking whether it's mandatory to create the table with own asp instructions and proper IDs in order to do this, or you can maybe suggest a way to achieve it with my current way of thinking.

**Added more explanation**: The purpose of the buttons is to delete the row (Which is being acquired from a Compact SQL database). I know you can achieve the same with a GridView, but I had a different problem with that method (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673256/cannot-set-label-text-values-in-a-modal-popup-from-gridview-values-in-boundfiel)) so I switched to `SqlCeDataAdapter` and `SqlCeDataCommand`, which are working very nicely!

My only problem was about how to insert the buttons in that context, but I am now in the middle of converting the table to an actual asp table with `runat=server` (rather than classic html), done programmatically, hoping that it can solve the problem. In the meantime, suggestions about fixing my initial idea or using a different way would be very welcome!

Comment: Instead label i suggest to use div with runat="server".
And if you can explain bit mote what is purpose of button, may be you can get more suggestions.

Comment: Use a [`GridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx). You would use a [`CommandField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield.aspx) to get the buttons you want on each row. Yours is about the worst possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Here is an example of how to create a button dynamically and then place it correctly into a cell. The example assumes that you have also created the rest of the table using the same system:

```
Button btnd = new Button();
btnd.ID = "del" + reader[0];
btnd.Text = "Borrar";

TableCell cedit = new TableCell();
cedit.ID = "edit" + reader[0];
cedit.Controls.Add(btnd);
//I previously created the row 'r'    
r.Cells.Add(cedit);
//I am inserting in Table2
Table2.Rows.Add(r);
```